# Region given by these inequalities in XY Plane

Tags: inequality, graphing-functions

Given  region as $ 0\leq x \leq y $ , $ x+y \leq 1$ . I did this as [image]

Is this correct ?

Comment: Looks good and correct. Try to sell this piece of art to some museum. It shows in a deep way that mathematicians are human.

Comment: @drhab Really , Are you gonna purchase it?

Comment: No, I will go to the museum to enjoy it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sketch is correct. The intercepts are both 1, if you want to label those.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. Find the bounds of the region by converting the inequalities to equalities. Here is a plot of the solution using wolfram alpha:
[image]